# Is it possible to add arrows heads on polyline in flutter?

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart, polyline, google-maps-flutter

I have implement a polyline in flutter

```
Map<PolylineId, Polyline> _mapPolylines = {};
  int _polylineIdCounter = 1;

  void _add() {
    final String polylineIdVal = 'polyline_id_$_polylineIdCounter';
    _polylineIdCounter++;
    final PolylineId polylineId = PolylineId(polylineIdVal);

    final Polyline polyline = Polyline(
      polylineId: polylineId,
      consumeTapEvents: true,
      color: Colors.red,
      width: 5,
      jointType: JointType.round,
      points: points, //_createPoints(),
    );

    setState(() {
      _mapPolylines[polylineId] = polyline;
    });
  }
```

and display it on the map

```
    return new GoogleMap(
        mapType: MapType.normal,
        markers: Set.from(Markers),
        initialCameraPosition: _kGooglePlex,
        polylines: Set<Polyline>.of(_mapPolylines.values),
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) async {
          _controller.complete(controller);
        });
```

I am using google_maps_flutter package and i am trying to indicate direction to my route.

Comment: There seems to be a related [feature request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17832) for google_maps_flutter in Github. Might be helpful for you to comment your use-case there and request to support arrows.

Comment: You can use the endCap or startCap property of polyline to customize the look at the vertices of the polyline. But arrowheads are not available by default so you would have to use custom caps. See this for reference: https://pub.dev/documentation/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/latest/google_maps_flutter_platform_interface/Cap/customCapFromBitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this issue. It is possible to show direction arrows on `Polyline` using the `Marker`. You can show `Marker` icons on `Polyline` at a specific interval based on your requirements. I show the arrow `Marker` between every three `LatLng` points, but I have to change this on the basis of zoom level. You can customise the default icon of `Marker` to an arrow icon using `BitmapDescriptor`. Below is a dummy image.

[image: directionMarkers]

You can do this like this:

```
// directionMarkers is a Set of Marker
directionMarkers.add(
      Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId(currentPosition.toString()),
        position: currentPosition,
        icon: movementArrow,  // Custom arrow Marker
        // Rotate the arrow in direction of movement. Func is defined below
        rotation: calculateBearing(previousPosition, currentPosition) - 90, 
        anchor: const Offset(0.5, 0.5),
      ),
    );
```

You can also rotate the arrows in the direction of `Polyline` using some mathematics. I generated this code to rotate the arrow using an AI tool. Here, `startPoint` is the user's current location, and `endPoint` is the position where the user will move, and we have to show a direction arrow from `start` to `end` point.

```
double calculateBearing(LatLng startPoint, LatLng endPoint) {
    final double startLat = toRadians(startPoint.latitude);
    final double startLng = toRadians(startPoint.longitude);
    final double endLat = toRadians(endPoint.latitude);
    final double endLng = toRadians(endPoint.longitude);

    final double deltaLng = endLng - startLng;

    final double y = Math.sin(deltaLng) * Math.cos(endLat);
    final double x = Math.cos(startLat) * Math.sin(endLat) -
        Math.sin(startLat) * Math.cos(endLat) * Math.cos(deltaLng);

    final double bearing = Math.atan2(y, x);

    return (toDegrees(bearing) + 360) % 360;
  }

  double toRadians(double degrees) {
    return degrees * (Math.pi / 180.0);
  }

  double toDegrees(double radians) {
    return radians * (180.0 / Math.pi);
  }
```

I can help you with this problem, as I made a feature to show the live location of a vehicle. So, I have explored this well :)